# Flutter - How to animate NavigationRail page transition [windows]

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, animation, navigation

I have implemented the NavigationRail as such:

```dart
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: [
          NavigationRail(
            destinations: const [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: Text("Home")),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings), label: Text("Settings"))
            ],
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          ),
          Expanded(child: pageBuilder())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget pageBuilder() {
    switch (_selectedIndex) {
      case 0:
        return const _HomePage();
      case 1:
        return const _SettingsPage();
      default:
        return const _HomePage();
    }
  }
}
```

With **_HomePage** :

```dart
class _HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const _HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<_HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text("HomePage"));
}
```

And **SettingsPage** is the same but says "SettingsPage" instead.

The question is, how can I animate the transition between these pages?
I cannot use Route and call `Navigator.of(context).push(_pageRouter())` under the switch statement as it will throw errors about building or such (it's a long one which I can provide if needed).

Is there any way to achieve this without using Route? or some workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple animation type. You can use switcher to change between animation
here is the [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) for widget. it will automatically change widget by animation.

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
    transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
        return ScaleTransition(scale: animation, child: child);
    },
    child: pageBuilder(),
)
```